# gitlab CI/CD run commands on external server

Tags: gitlab

I want to use gitlabs CI/CD to deploy my app on a external server. i have the IP, username and password, and i understand i need to connect through SSH. How can i runn all the nessesary commands on the server side. Server runs on linux.

Currently i just get the code from reposiroty and to the npm build:prod and npm serve:prod for the API and npm start for the UI. How can i do the same chain of cammands with gitlab CI/CD? Or is this even possible? I basically want it to run similarily like jenkins works. But since the code is already on gitlab, it might be simplerer to let gitlab to handle this process instead of installing and setting up jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to SSH to your machine from within GitLab CI, you probably should setup [ssh key authentication](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server), since you can't just type in the password inside the CI.

When you've got that set up, you have to store the private key in an environment variable so you can use it in the CI job. How to do that can be found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/).

The last part is actually executing commands over ssh. That can be done in the following way:

```sh
ssh <host> '
    command1;
    command2;
'
```